# wordpress insert user with variables not working

Tags: php, database, wordpress, plugins

i try to develop a plugin for my wordpress installation where users are automatically added with a custom registration form. Therefore I am using wp_insert_user. It looks like this, but isnt working.

```
$login_name     = $_POST['clientname']; 

$userdata = array(
    'user_login'  =>  $login_name,
    'user_pass'   =>  wp_generate_password()
    );

wp_insert_user( $userdata );
```

Instead of $login_name I tried a specific name like 'max' and it works fine. What is the problem? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does `var_dump($_POST)` show what you expect?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried var_dump ($_POST) and it showed me what i was expecting, but i noticed that i was using two words with a blank space between them for $login_name. I am using one word now and it works.